# What are you using for Ext JS config objects' intellisense?

Tags: ide, intellisense, extjs

I am wondering what IDE RIA developers use for Ext JS development? Does any IDE has config objects itellisence?

I found [this itellisence file](http://www.spket.com/ext-intellisense-visual-studio.html) for Visual Studio. Also Aptana has support for Ext JS, but not for config objects. Spket has IDE is it good? Does anybody use it?

Comment: I use Netbeans for extjs, and manually check the config from the documentation. Thanks for raising this, would be nice to see if someone has solution for this

Answer (score 0):

You can try Ext Designer for the Design of your application.

Answer (score 0):

I use Komodo, they have support for popular libraries like dojo yui and Extjs